# How to get a view in an Ember.js Router app

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-old-router

If I need to refer to the view for a specific controller, how would I get it in a router based application.

I can get a controller like this

```
App.router.get('myController')
```

But the controller **shouldn't and usually doesn't** know about the view so

```
App.router.get('myController.view')
```

^-- Will not work

This also will not work:

```
App.router.get('myView')
```

Is there a correct way to grab it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App.router.get('myController.view')` should work fine, `connectOutlet` sets the view by the outlet's name onto the controller.

However, it is the outlet that is defined on the controller, not the view, so to get a basic view you will need to access it from the ApplicationController.

`App.router.get('applicationController.view')`

Comment: So what you are saying is if I want the view for controller N on the hierarchy, I need to ask controller N-1 for the view? How would I ask the `applicationController` for its view then?

Comment: `App.router.get('applicationController.view')`

Comment: Not working , It says Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: That question is from 2012, Ember has changed a lot since, and views are being phased out anyway.