# how to get a custom view in Ember from a controller?

Tags: ember.js

I stumbled into a similar question here - [How to get a view in an Ember.js Router app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591554/how-to-get-a-view-in-an-ember-js-router-app)

But that doesn't help me. Suppose on my users.hbs template i have this:

```
{{view App.CarouselView contentBinding="App.carouselData" elementId="new-users"}}
```

And on my UsersController I like to access that view. How do i do that? I have that vie access like so:

module.exports = App.CarouselView = Ember.View.extend({...})

I'd like to change its contentBinding on the fly so I need a way to access that instance so i can show a different set of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the official [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/) (under *A Note on coupling*):

> In ember.js, templates get their properties from controllers, which in turn decorate a model. This means that templates know about controllers and controllers know about models, but the reverse is not true. A model knows nothing about which (if any) controllers are decorating it, and controller does not know which views are presenting its properties.

That said, you should rather swap out *the content* of `App.carouselData` instead and since it's bound the view will get updated.

Hope it helps.